# jQuery-UI plugin with datetimepicker is displayed incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to use the following datetimepicker in my app https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker (Rails 5.0.2) in a form. I've managed to successfully implement datepicker from jquery-ui
(https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails) and I am using it in the following way:

```
# app/views/workshop/_form.html.erb
<%= f.label :end_date, 'End date' %>
<%= f.text_field :end_date, class: 'form-control' %>
```

And in the javascripts directory I have:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/workshop.coffee
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#workshop_end_date').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

I have copied jquery.datetimepicker.css and .js into my assets from the repo and used code:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#workshop_end_date').datetimepicker({
    format:'d.m.Y H:i'
    });
```

And when I click on the field a widget is displayed but it's missing basically all the calendar/hour fields, only arrow icons are present, see below.

[image: Missing days]

What am I doing wrong, how can I use this plugin correctly? Should I include some other files from the repo or is it not the way to do it at all.

I am very new to Rails, I don't get the asset pipeline very good yet so it may be a silly question but I don't see simple instructions anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to mix two JavaScript/CSS formats for the same form field. It will definitely result in something unintended. Drop the jquery-ui datepicker since date is already part of datetimepicker. And someone has packaged datetimepicker as a gem so you can use that and follow the instructions at https://github.com/shekibobo/xdan-datetimepicker-rails.